# Pinata pinList API Fetching Unpinned Images and Files

Tags: solidity, contract-development, metamask, nft, ipfs

I am encountering an issue with Pinata's API (https://api.pinata.cloud/data/pinList) where despite unpining several images and files from my Pinata Cloud account, the API continues to fetch the unpinned data along with the pinned data. This inconsistency is causing discrepancies in the fetched NFTs, and I need assistance in resolving this issue.

for reference i am attaching my code here

```
    const [nfts, setNFTs] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchNFTs = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios({
                    method: "get",
                    url: "https://api.pinata.cloud/data/pinList",
                    headers: {
                        'pinata_api_key': pinataApiKey,
                        'pinata_secret_api_key': pinataApiSecret,
                    },
                });
                const pinnedNFTs = response.data.rows.filter(row => row.mime_type === 'image/png'); // Filter by MIME type
                const nftsData = pinnedNFTs.map(row => ({
                    name: row.metadata.name,
                    description: row.metadata.description,
                    image: `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${row.ipfs_pin_hash}`, // Construct the complete image URL
                    externalUrl: row.metadata.external_url,
                }));
                setNFTs(nftsData);
                console.log('nfts data' , nftsData)
                console.log(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching NFTs:", error);
            }
        };
    
        fetchNFTs();
    }, []);
```